# How to find a system job by the content of the stored procedure in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I currently find a system job by the date and time it was last run e.g.

The following query below returns a hundred jobs that last ran on the 1st August 2016 at both 8:37 and 8:44, and lists them in order of newest to oldest times.

```
SELECT TOP 100
        *
FROM    ( SELECT    j.[name] ,
                    jh.run_date ,
                    jh.run_time
          FROM      msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
                    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON jh.job_id = j.job_id
                                                            AND jh.step_id = 0
          GROUP BY  j.[name] ,
                    jh.run_date ,
                    jh.run_time
        ) AS Results
WHERE   
    run_date = '20160801'
    AND run_time IN(
    '083700'
    , '084400'
    )
    ORDER BY 
    [run_time] DESC
```

The job I'm trying to find runs a stored procedure, and I've been trying to discover a way to search through the queries of each stored procedure for the string 'datetime_entered = ' and also 'user_entered = '.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Note:

It can be assumed that I have all my software updated to the latest versions.

I also use SQL Prompt add on for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is preferable because it allows you to search the procedure definitions:

```
SELECT  
    p.name 
    , c.[definition]
    , [Results].[job_id]
    , [Results].[name]
    , [Results].[srvname]
    , [Results].[step_id]
    , [Results].[command]
FROM    
    ( 
        SELECT 
            j.[job_id]   
            , j.[name] 
            , s.[srvname]
            , jh.run_date 
            , jh.run_time 
            , js.[step_id]
            , js.command 
            , CASE 
                WHEN js.command LIKE 'exec %' THEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(js.command, 5, LEN(js.command) - 4)) > 0 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(js.command, 5, LEN(js.command) - 4), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(js.command, 5, LEN(js.command) - 4)), LEN(js.command) - CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(js.command, 5, LEN(js.command) - 4))), ']', ''), '[', ''), 'dbo.', '')))
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(js.command, 5, LEN(js.command) - 4)
                    END
                ELSE ''
            END AS StoredProcedure
        FROM      
            msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = 0
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS js ON js.job_id = j.job_id
            INNER JOIN master.dbo.sysservers s ON  s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
        WHERE j.[enabled] = 1 
    ) AS Results
    INNER JOIN sys.objects p ON p.name LIKE '%' + Results.[StoredProcedure] + '%'
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules c ON p.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE   
    run_date = '20160801'
    AND run_time IN ( '083700', '084400' )
    AND ( command LIKE N'%datetime_entered = %' OR c.[definition] LIKE N'%datetime_entered = %' )
    AND ( command LIKE N'%user_entered = %' OR c.[definition] LIKE N'%user_entered = %' )
GROUP BY 
    p.name 
    , c.[definition]
    , [Results].[job_id]
    , [Results].[name]
    , [Results].[srvname]
    , [Results].[step_id]
    , [Results].[command];
```

Note: Currently needs to be run on each database.

Answer (score 3):

[Use SYSJobSteps](http://sqltidbits.com/scripts/search-sql-server-agent-job-steps-specific-keyword-text-or-stored-procedure)... and in the command part enter the content of stored proc you wish to search for..

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT  j.job_id,
    s.srvname,
    j.name,
    js.step_id,
    js.command,
    j.enabled 
FROM    dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN    dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON  js.job_id = j.job_id 
JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
    ON  s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
WHERE   js.command LIKE N'%KEYWORD_SEARCH%'
```